# MySQL GROUP BY and HAVING Clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a script to show the names of every city with at least two customers, along with the number of customers in that city.

Here's what I have but I cannot figure out how to get the number of customers. 
Am I close?

```
SELECT CONCAT (FName,' ',LName) AS Customers, city 
FROM Customer
GROUP BY City
HAVING COUNT(CID) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use count(*)

```
 SELECT city , count(*)
 FROM Customer 
 GROUP BY City HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

As u can see from this example:

```
SELECT Employees.LastName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM (Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID)
GROUP BY LastName
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 10;
```

you must enter COUNT (CID) in the select

Comment: ... and can use the alias in the `HAVING`